# how to use a larger 'max_depth' in xgboost

Tags: parameters, xgboost

I'm using xgboost to fit data which have 2 features. I've setting 'max_depth' to 30 but i get a tree with 11 depth. Trees with 11 depth didn't fit will with data compare to BP-net.

```
    df_new = pd.DataFrame()
    df_new['ua'] = df['ua_norm']
    df_new['va'] = df['va_norm']
    df_new['pow'] = df['pow_unit_cap_norm']

    param_grid = {"n_estimators": [1],
                  'max_depth': [30],
                  'colsample_bytree': [1.0],
                  "alpha": [10]
                  }
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(
        xgb.XGBRegressor(),
        param_grid,
        cv=3,
        n_jobs=3,
        verbose=3,
        scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
        return_train_score=True
    )


    grid_search.fit(np.array(df_new[['ua', 'va']]), np.array(df_new['pow']))
    model = grid_search.best_estimator_
    model.get_booster().feature_names = ['ua', 'va']
    tree_df = model.get_booster().trees_to_dataframe()
    tree_df.to_csv('tree.csv', index=False)
    scr = xgb.to_graphviz(model, num_trees=0)
    # src.format = "jpg"
    scr.view("./tree")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKKVR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using such a large value for max_depth and alpha?

The maximum tree depth is defaulted to three (3) and rarely needs to go higher than five (5) (Tseng, 2018)...For trees, it tends to be best to set a high L2 (lambda) value and L1 (alpha) to zero (Chris, 2016)
https://towardsdatascience.com/mastering-xgboost-2eb6bce6bc76

By the way, alpha is a regularization parameter, such high value decreases the tree  depth.